# How to update postgres password when authenticating to RDS via STS token (IAM)

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

Rds has supported IAM-based authentication into postgres for a while now, but I don't see any discussion about getting it working within a django app happening anywhere.

It's a simple enough system - your app runs with a service role (or has an iam user's access key and secret), to which permission to connect as a particular db user has been attached, via a standard IAM policy. Whenever the app needs to connect to the database, it uses the AWS SDK to request a token from STS, which is authorized via the service role so no credentials are required.  It uses the received token as the password when connecting to the database, and the database must have a user with that name which is configured to use the iam authentication mechanism. But the tokens are only good for 15 minutes. This means that the connection factory needs to set a max-age for the connection that is less than 15 minutes, and it needs to request a new token/password every time it opens a new connection. Django expects a password to be set at application initialization, not dynamically generated every time a new connection is made.

This seems like the kind of thing that django ought to support natively, rather than requiring middleware (or creative hacks of the the config dict's __getattr__ method). So much so that I'm loathe to implement such a hack without asking the wider community about a solution.  I'm not a django developer.  I'm the devops guy trying to make a django app work in production.  I've had no luck with google searches about credential rotation or dynamic settings.

The obvious solution would be to allow a callable to be assigned to the password, but that doesn't work, currently, without a hack to the __getattr__ method of the database's configuration dict. Am I missing something obvious about how to set this up? I'm using a typical nginx->gunicorn->django deployment - all in the same container. It seems like it ought to be easier than it appears to be, so I hope I'm just missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure how if helps much, but *"the connection factory needs to set a max-age for the connection that is less than 15 minutes"* seems like an incorrect assumption. Once the connection is established, you can keep the connection open beyond that limit.  The 15 minute limit only applies to how long the temporary token can be used to *establish* a connection. Also *"it needs to request a new token/password every time it opens a new connection"* isn't quite right, either.  The tokens are not single-use.  Multiple connections can be opened with the same unexpired token.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was true about the connection staying open beyond the token's expiration - the AWS documentation doesn't make that clear at all. If they don't stay authenticated after expiration, it is likely easier to refresh the token for every connection and to set CONN_AX_AGE slightly less than 15 minutes than to set up a separate thread of execution which just updates the token every <15 minutes. But I'd happily accept an answer that does set up a periodic refresh if it also includes code for updating the credential for subsequent connections that may or may not occur in the next 15

Comment: Incidentally, hacking __getattr__ in the db config doesn't work, because the values are retrieved from that dict and stored elsewhere by the settings system. The best idea I've seen so far is to inherit from the standard postgresql psycopg client and overload the get_connection_params() method.